# VBA Code to convert rows into PDF files start to print blank pages after sometime

Tags: ms-access, vba

I wrote a VBA code to print every row of my table into pdf files while creating directories for them.

At first it look great, it doesn't show any kind of error but when the loop ends (around 1200 rows) if I go check the files created, some worked perfectly while others are just blank pages.

Any idea why this might be happening?

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command0_Click()
Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim ps As DAO.Recordset
    Dim MyFileName As String
    Dim mypath As String
    Dim temp As String


    'mypath = "C:\Docs\"

    Set db = CurrentDb()

    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [TABLE]", dbOpenSnapshot)

   Do While Not rs.EOF
        On Error Resume Next
        b = "C:\Docs\" & rs("ENTERPRISE")
        MkDir (b)

        b1 = "C:\Docs\" & rs("ENTERPRISE") & "\" & "ECONOMICS"
        MkDir (b1)

        b2 = "C:\Docs\" & rs("ENTERPRISE") & "\" & "ECONOMICS" & "\" & Year(rs("DATE")) & "-" & Month(rs("DATE"))
        MkDir (b2)

        a = b2 & "\" & rs("NUM") & "-" & rs("ITEM")
        MkDir (a)

        mypath = a & "\"
        temp = rs("DOC_LANC")
        MyFileName = rs("NUM") & rs("ITEM") & ".PDF"

        DoCmd.OpenReport "PDF", acViewReport, , "[DOC_LANC]='" & temp & "'"
        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "", acFormatPDF, mypath & MyFileName
        DoCmd.Close acReport, "PDF"
        DoEvents

        rs.MoveNext

    Loop

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I have done this for a dataset of thousands without this issue. Can you identify a record producing blank? Modify the SQL statement to pull only that record. Is PDF good?

Comment: I already did that and the pdf was good. I'm trying other solutions here and i found out that if I limit my loop to get only the first 200 lines it works perfectly. Don't know if this can be a problem with access memory?

Comment: Think I found the problem but got another one. If I remove the line "On Error Resume Next" I get run-time error '2501' after sometime. Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: When I did this I was outputting about 65,000 records. I had to do it in batches of 5,000 or the program crashed. What is the exact error message?

Comment: Error 2010 cannot open any more tables

Comment: The PDFs are not auto opening? I think the OutputTo command AutoStart argument defaults to False. So if PDFs are not opening that must the case and not the issue. Sorry, I have no other solution than to run small batches. As I said, I could do batches of 5000 records.

Comment: They are auto opening but after awhile it stops

Comment: Set AutoStart argument to False. True must be the default.